# Force django's {% static %} to fail silently

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm using a custom static file storage:

```
class StaticFilesStorage(CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass
```

(the CachedFilesMixin is for cache busting).

My problem is that when I have in my template `{% static "file_that_does_not_exist.jpg" %}` the template isn't rendered and I get an exception

```
ValueError: The file 'file_that_does_not_exist.jpg' could not be found with <StaticFilesStorage object at 0x03AE4C70>.
```

It fails because the file isn't on S3 so S3BotoStorage can't serve it but it means that if for example my logo.jpg file is missing for some reason then the entire website goes down and that's not good..

Is there a way to force `{% static %}` to fail silently?

Comment: Can you write full error trace?

Comment: you can create a custom django template filter. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters  search the file, if not exists,  just return a empty or default image.

Comment: Thanks levi, I considered this option, the downside is that I need to edit my entire project and change everywhere {% static %} to {% mystatic %}

Answer (score 0):

For now this is what works for me:

```
class StaticFilesStorage(CachedFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    def exists(self, name):
        return True
```

This overrides `S3BotoStorage.exists()` so `{% static %}` doesn't raise an Exception and generates the S3 URL (which gives 404 to the browser but that's OK).